# Rendering taking too long. Is there a way to improve it?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation, gpu

I recently tried to render in Blender, but, it is taking the a ridiculously long time to render a frame. I've tried rendering on my windows laptop which has a NVIDIA GT 520M, 8GB of ram, and a 64-bit operating system and people told me that using the GPU won't accelerate rendering much. Instead I decided to render on my school computer. The school computer has a: 
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 760 GPU
Integrated with 2GB GDDR5 memory, 256-bit memory interface

This took 20 mins a frame, I then thought my animation is 2000 frames long. 1 frame takes 20 mins, 20*2000 is 40000 mins. 40000 mins equals to 667 hours which equal to 30 days. I would never be able to hand up my assignment on time. I watched many tutorials on rendering and trying the tips that people gave me but it didn't improve the rendering time.

Here's my blender file: [image]
(note, it is in CPU render instead of GPU render because I am currently working on it on my macbook air)

[image]

First screenshot of the render settings.

[image]

Second screenshot of the render settings.

Comment: You might want to let a renderfarm render you project. [Sheepit](https://www.sheepit-renderfarm.com/) is a free renderfarm, you can render other projects and let others render your project. Its a give and take.

Comment: what is difference in your screenshots ? they are same

Comment: Why not use "openGL render animation" from the Render dropdown. It will render textures and it will be lightning fast compared to the 20 minutes per frame you'd expect in cycles. It won't look fantastic..but it will render the entire thing in about 20 minutes. -- if you are really stuck...

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to speed up render times.

1. Enable auto tile addon to set tile size correctly.

User preferences => Addons => Enable Render: Auto Tile Size => Save Settings

2. By utilizing denoising you should be able to decrease render samples.
   Scene tab => Check denoising box
3. Bake your materials. Its too complex to explain here, so check out [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sB09T--_ZvU) tutorial.

Answer (score -1):

I have render out a couple of animations and unless you have a beast of a computer it is going to take a while. If you aren't afraid to through some money around I would suggest you use a render farm. I mostly use blendergrid.